# Passing a FORTRAN EXTERNAL data type to C

Tags: c, fortran, external

Another FORTRAN/C related question,

If this is my Fortran

```
PROGRAM test

  IMPLICIT NONE

  EXTERNAL pass

     CALL ccode(pass)

END PROGRAM
```

Where pass refers to another subroutine

c code

```
void ccode_(what should go here?)

{
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `_ccode`?

Comment: I think it is ok as it is

Comment: Isn't using `iso_c_binding` a nicer way to go? Different compilers, do the underscore name mapping differently...

Comment: I think I have come to far without, I am already passing objects, allocatables etc

Comment: Actually I think I had it backwards. IIRC the C compiler normally prepends an underscore, so I'm guessing you'd need to `CALL _ccode` in FORTRAN.  (Unless there's some other magic going on somewhere.)  Regardless, I'd suggest trying a function pointer as the argument to your C function -- but you'll need to know the signature for `pass`.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit

Comment: External means little, you must find the definition of `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what `pass` is. Specifically:

- What parameters does it take?
- What is its return value type?
- What is its calling convention?

Once you know that, you can write the C code accordingly. So, suppose that it is a function receiving a `double` and returning an `int` with the `cdecl` calling convention, then you declare it like so:

```
typedef int (__cdecl *FuncType)(double);


void ccode_(FuncType)
{
    int retval = func(42.0);
}
```